# Smart tables for Sphinx (reStructuredText)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Are there any smart table extensions for using tables in RST?

It is too tedious to use tables with multiple columns having to type each row and column.
Especially if I want to merge or split the cells in the table as shown below:

[image]

I am trying to get the above table using flat-table. Can anyone suggest on how to get this?

```
.. flat-table:: Characteristics of the BLE badge
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Col 1
     - Col 2
     - Col 3
   * - :rspan:`2` 0xfee7
     - 0xfec7
     - WRITE
   * - 0xfec8
     - INDICATE
   * - 0xfec9
     - READ
   * - 0xfee0
     - 0xfee1
     - NOTIFY, READ, WRITE
```

Using the [Linuxdoc](https://koen.vervloesem.eu/blog/using-flat-tables-in-restructuredtext-with-sphinx-for-column-and-row-spans/) extension to use the flat-tables.

Comment: Does [grid tables](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#grid-tables) do what you want?

Comment: i am ok for grid or flat table, as long as I am able to merge the columns or rows as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: were you able to get grid tables to work for you? If not, edit your question with what you tried. Grid table syntax can be tricky.

Comment: No, I was not able to get the grid with the kind of columns that I need. I get a normal grid table (the code for which is already in the question).

Comment: Please share what you tried with grid tables by editing your answer and pasting your reStructuredText of the grid table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the linuxdoc Python package:

```bash
pip install linuxdoc
```

Next, add [linuxdoc.rstFlatTable](https://return42.github.io/linuxdoc/install.html) to the list of extensions in your Sphinx project's conf.py:

```py
extensions = [
    'linuxdoc.rstFlatTable',
]
```

The [linuxdoc](https://return42.github.io/linuxdoc/linuxdoc-howto/table-markup.html#flat-table) manual contains an example that features combinations of row and column spans.

The following reStructuredText produces your table:

```
.. flat-table:: Spanning table cells
   :header-rows: 2

   * - :rspan:`1` Col 1
     - :rspan:`1` Col 2
     - :rspan:`1` Col 3
     - :cspan:`2` Col 4

   * - Col 4a
     - Col 4b
     - Col 4c

   * - 1
     - 2
     - 3
     - 4a
     - 4b
     - 4c
```

Note that if you set *header-rows* option to 1, linuxdoc produces a malformed table.

Comment: I get: WARNING: Unknown directive type "flat-table".

Comment: @Sushivam I updated my answer to address this.